# Limit of integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits

Let $g: \mathbb{C}\times[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuous function and

$$g(t)=g(h_0,t)=\lim\nolimits_{h\to h_0} g(h,t) \ \forall t\in \mathbb{R}$$

Is the following result/reasoning correct ? If we have a sequence of functions, we need uniform convergence to pass the limit inside the integral, but it seems it works everytime here. Or there is a flaw ?

We have

$$\lim_{h\to h_0} \int_a^b g(h,t)dt= \int_a^b g(t)dt$$

because

> **Idea 1:**
>
> $$\forall t\in[a,b], \ \forall
> > \epsilon >0, \exists \delta(t)>0\text{
> > such that }|g(h,t)-g(t)|<\epsilon \
> > \forall |h-h_0|<\delta(t)$$
>
> Then if
>   $|h-h_0|<\delta=\inf_{t\in[a,b]}
> > \delta(t)$,
>
> $$|g(h,t)-g(t)|<\epsilon \ \forall
> > |h-h_0|<\delta(t), \ \forall
> > t\in[a,b]$$
>
> Thus
>
> $$\left|\int_a^b
> > (g(h,t)-g(t))dt\right|\le \int_a^b
> > |g(h,t)-g(t)|dt\le (b-a)\epsilon$$
>
> **Doesn't work if $\inf_{t\in[a,b]}
> > \delta(t)=0$, see George's comment.**

~

> **Idea 2:** (added after George's comment)
>
> Let $\overline{B(h_0, \gamma)}\subset
> > C$ a closed ball. Resctrict $g$ to $
> > \overline{B(h_0, \gamma)}\times[a,b]$.
>   Because it is continuous on a compact,
>   this function will be uniformly
>   continuous. Thus
>
> $$\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists
> > \delta>0 \ : \
> > |g(h,t)-g(h_0,t)|<\epsilon \ \forall
> > |h-h_0|<\min(\delta, \gamma)$$
>
> and
>
> $$\left|\int_a^b
> > (g(h,t)-g(t))dt\right|\le \int_a^b
> > |g(h,t)-g(t)|dt\le (b-a)\epsilon$$
>
> if $|h-h_0|<\min(\delta, \gamma)$.
>
> Does this one work ;) ?

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: The proof would fall apart if $\inf_{t\in[a,b]}\delta(t)$ was zero. You want a single $\delta > 0$ to apply for all t, for which uniform continuity is needed.

Comment: Thank you! I felt there was a problem with this infimum, but I could not tell what.
I found another way to proceed, and added it to the question. Does it fail as well ?

Comment: Yes that works! I could add it as an answer, but it hardly seems worth it now that you have the correct answer in the post.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for your valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the second idea was the right one: considering $g$ on a compact to have it uniformly continuous. See my message above.